# Landscape-api couldn't parse value as data

Tags: command-line, landscape

I've been using the landscape-api command line to create and edit scripts in Landscape for a while. Recently, however, I started getting an error:

```
Couldn't parse value <code> as data
```

The command I'm running is:

```
landscape-api edit-script <script_ID> --code <file_name>
```

The error also occurs if I enter the code as text instead of a file name.

I only noticed the error in the last couple weeks, and it was working fine as of a little over a month ago. Any ideas?

Comment: There seems to be a regression in the api client snap. I have filed a bug (LP:#2022819). Considering it worked a few weeks ago, you might have some luck reverting the snap to the previous version using `sudo snap revert landscape-client` to unblock you in the meantime.